# Import existing src into root directory of Eclipse Project?

Tags: eclipse, import

I am using Eclipse Indigo. I already have some code that is stored in a repository outside of my workplace directory. The repository contains various projects and so it wouldn't make sense to include it in the workspace. I have created an empty Java ME project and I now want to import various source files and folders by linking them in. I've played around with various settings, but Eclipse insists on creating a top level folder to hold them. To be clear, the hierarchy is:

```
Java ME Project -> Unwanted Top Level Folder -> Source Files and Folders
```

Can I make it instead:

```
Java ME Project -> Source Files and Folders
```

**Update**: Thanks Srikanth for the [doc link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-70.htm). According to it, the file system should have a "Create selected folders only" option, but it isn't showing in my version (3.7.0.v20110530)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not seem to be available in Eclipse 3.7. In 3.6 (and maybe lower) it is possible though. While importing the existing src select **Create selected folders only** radio button.It will import only the wanted folders.

Comment: Indigo doesn't seem to provide that option. Only "Overwrite existing resources without warning", "Create top-level folder", "Create links in workspace", "Create virtual folders", "Create link locations relative to..."

Comment: Once check this. http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-70.htm

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: There is no screenshot.Once check it.